# Закрывается AlertDialog

Tags: android, alert

Есть AlertDialog, в котором два EditText, куда вводятся данные, при этом нужно, чтобы AlertDialog не закрывался после того как данные не подходят, или не введены, а он закрывается.

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            ViewGroup viewGroupFab = findViewById(R.id.layoutParent);
            final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create, viewGroupFab);

            final EditText subject = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_subject);
            final EditText text = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

            builder.setView(view);

            builder.setTitle(note_new);
            builder.setPositiveButton(add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    String strSub = removeSeparator(subject);
                    String strText = removeSeparator(text);

                    if (checked(strSub) && checked(strText)){
                        writable(strSub, strText);
                        prepareData();
                    } else
                        message(error);
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton(cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, вот это:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setMessage("Test for preventing dialog close");
builder.setPositiveButton("Test", 
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            //Do nothing here because we override this button later to change the close behaviour. 
            //However, we still need this because on older versions of Android unless we 
            //pass a handler the button doesn't get instantiated
        }
    });
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
//Overriding the handler immediately after show is probably a better approach than OnShowListener as described below
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new    View.OnClickListener()
  {            
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          Boolean wantToCloseDialog = false;
          //Do stuff, possibly set wantToCloseDialog to true then...
          if(wantToCloseDialog)
              dialog.dismiss();
          //else dialog stays open. Make sure you have an obvious way to close the dialog especially if you set cancellable to false.
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

В AlertDialog нажатия на кнопку всегда приводят к закрытию диалога! Для решения Вашей проблемы - Вам следует обратить внимание на DialogFragment.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

В нём Вы сможете реализовать проверку + как бонус при повороте экрана диалог никуда не пропадёт.